# convert yyyymmdd to mm/dd/yyyy on csv file

Tags: date, csv, awk

Please help. I need a unix shell command for the sample.csv file with records below:

```
1231,aaa,bbb,20161001,20161002,hi-ax
1231,aaa,ccc,20161002,20161003,hi-ay 
1231,aaa,ddd,20161001,20161007,hi-az
```

And output should be:

```
1231,aaa,bbb,10/01/2016,10/02/2016,hi-ax
1231,aaa,ccc,10/02/2016,10/03/2016,hi-ay
1231,aaa,ddd,10/01/2016,10/07/2016,hi-az
```

Can someone fix the this command? I've tried it but it won't work without a delimiter:

```
awk -F, '{split($4,a,"");$4=a[2]"/"a[3]"/"a[1]}1' OFS=, sample.csv > output.csv
```

Answer (score 3):

I would rather go with a function for something like this, it makes it more maintainable, e.g.:

*convert-date.awk*

```awk
function ruin_utc(d) {
  year  = substr(d, 1, 4)
  month = substr(d, 5, 2)
  day   = substr(d, 7, 2)
  return month "/" day "/" year
}
```

You can now use the function like this:

```
awk -f convert-date.awk -e '{ $4 = ruin_utc($4); $5 = ruin_utc($5) } 1' FS=, OFS=, sample.csv
```

Or more portable:

*convert-date2.awk*

```awk
function ruin_utc(d) {
  year  = substr(d, 1, 4)
  month = substr(d, 5, 2)
  day   = substr(d, 7, 2)
  return month "/" day "/" year
}
{ $4 = ruin_utc($4); $5 = ruin_utc($5) } 
1
```

Run it like this:

```
awk -f convert-date.awk FS=, OFS=, sample.csv
```

Output:

```
1231,aaa,bbb,10/01/2016,10/02/2016,hi-ax
1231,aaa,ccc,10/02/2016,10/03/2016,hi-ay
1231,aaa,ddd,10/01/2016,10/07/2016,hi-az
```

Comment: I'm running the function and command at the same time and getting an error: Syntax error: `(' is not expected. Or I might be running it incorrectly...how?

Comment: @xoxopepper: does it work if you put the script between the quotes into the `convert-date.awk` file? Which version of awk are you using

Comment: @xoxopepper: See `convert-date2.awk`.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU awk for gensub():

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
function cvt(dt) { return gensub(/(....)(..)(..)/,"\\2/\\3/\\1",1,dt) }
{ $4=cvt($4); $5=cvt($5); print }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
1231,aaa,bbb,10/01/2016,10/02/2016,hi-ax
1231,aaa,ccc,10/02/2016,10/03/2016,hi-ay
1231,aaa,ddd,10/01/2016,10/07/2016,hi-az
```